# Explicación negación lógica en un array

Tags: php

tengo una duda de concepto, estoy intentando realizar una aplicación y me encuentro con un if que no me queda del todo claro como funciona, alguien me lo podría explicar?

```
     static $grande = array();
     for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $grande[$i] = false;
    }
```

Hasta aquí es un array con 10 valores = false

Ahora lo recorro:

```
        for ( $i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++ ) {

      
             if(!$grande[$i]){    //QUE HACE ESTA INSTRUCCION?
             break;      
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP, `!` pertenece al grupo de los [**Operadores lógicos**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) y significa `Not`, como explica el Manual de PHP. Y, por su definición, **devuelve `true` si el valor evaluado no es `true`**.

Concretamente en tu código:

```
         if(!$grande[$i]){    //QUE HACE ESTA INSTRUCCION?
```

Lo que se pregunta es si el valor de `$grande[$i]` no es verdadero, o, lo que es lo mismo, si es falso.

Sería similar a esto:

```
         if($grande[$i]===false){    //QUE HACE ESTA INSTRUCCION?
```

Ese operador se puede usar también con funciones que devuelvan valores booleanos, por ejemplo:

```
#Si $grande No(t) está vacío
var_dump(!empty($grande));   #bool(true)
```

Que sería lo contrario de:

```
#Si $grande está vacío
var_dump(empty($grande));    #bool(false)
```

Se puede usar también con comparaciones (que como tales devuelven valores booleanos). Por ejemplo:

```
#¿1 No(t) es mayor que 2?
$a=!(1 > 2);
var_dump($a);    #bool(true)
```

Y sin negación:

```
#¿1 es mayor que 2?
$a=(1 > 2);
var_dump($a);    #bool(false)
```

Comment: Genial como siempre, gracias.